# how to get the value from a field in hook_node_load($nodes, types)

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a **hook_node_load()**, when I dsm($nodes), it returns an array, I need to get the value from field_tt_status (contains 1 or 0). I know I have to do something like

```
$status = $nodes['field_tt_status']['und']['0']['value'];
```

but it that doesnt work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$nodes` variable is an array of node objects. You either need to loop through the array and extract the field values, or get the first item off the array and use that. For example:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  if ($node->type == 'content_type') {
    $field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_tt_status');
    $status = $field_items[0]['value'];
  }
}
```